# nHibernate locking - does LockMode UPGRADE block subsequent a NONE read on the same row

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, locking, race-condition

We have an card order process which can take a few seconds to run.  Data in this process is run using the LockMode.UPGRADE in nHibernate.

A second (webhook) process with runs with LockMode.NONE is occasionally being triggered before the first order process completed creating a race condition and appears to be using the original row data.  Its not being blocked until the first is complete so is getting old data.

Since our database is not running with NO WAIT or any of the other SNAPSHOT COMMITTED settings.

My Question is: Can lockmode.none somehow ignore the UPGRADE lock and read the old data (cache perhaps?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade locks are for preventing another transaction to acquire the same data for upgrade too.

A transaction running in read committed mode without additional lock will still be able to read them. You need an exclusive lock for blocking read committed reads (provided they are without snapshot isolation level). Read more on [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx).

As far as I know, NHibernate does not provide a way to issue exclusive locks on entity reads. (You will have them by actually updating the entities in the transaction.) You may workaround this by using `CreateSQLQuery` for issuing your locks directly in DB. Or in your webhook process, acquire upgrade lock too.

But this path will surely lead to deadlocks or lock contentions.

More generally, avoiding explicitly locking by adapting code patterns is preferable. I have just written an example [here](/a/43341347/1178314), see the "no explicit lock" solution.

As for your webhook process, is there really any differences between those two situation?

1. It obtains its data, which was not having any update lock on it, but before it processes it, its data get updated by the order process.
2. It obtains its data, including some which was having an update lock on them.

Generally you will still have the same trouble to solve, and avoiding 2. will not resolve 1. Here too, that is the way the process work with its data that need to be adapted for supporting concurrency. (Hint: using long running transactions for solving 1. will surely lead to locks contention too.)